# SCCM - Accept a dialog box via command line to uninstall a simple MSI

Tags: command-line, prompt, uninstallation, sccm

I'm trying to uninstall a simple MSI via SCCM but when I start the command line, this message appears "Are you sure to uninstall this application ?" and I have the "Yes or No" choice.

I tried with this command line: msiexec /x {D582312F-07B5-434A-8CBB-F6793440CD0C} /qn

But nothing is happening because I think the command line is stuck when the question is asked.

Anybody have had the same problem and have a solution to respond "Yes"?

Thansk a lot in advance,
G. Cotting

Comment: If this is the default msi prompt of are you sure qn has to supress it and answer with yes, that's the whole point of /qn. You could either try with logging and see if that gives any clue to what is the problem or you could try /qb instead which should still not ask questions but would prompt for errors at least (e.g. /qn would ignore a typo in the guid and fail silently /qb would tell you that the package does not exist)

Comment: I agree with Syberdoor, if you enable logging with "/L*V C:\temp\uninstall.log" you should be able to see where the uninstall is stopping. Confirm that it is the prompt causing the problem before investigating further.

You could also upload the log file and I'd be happy to take a look if that helps.